# SSL Protocol Error on 16.04, nothing showing in error logs

Tags: apache2, ssl, openssl, aws, mod-ssl

So when I go to https://example.org I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. I have checked my Security Groups on AWS (ec2/**ubuntu 16.04 server**) and I do in fact have port 443 open on both TCP/HTTPS. My only sites-enabled is `default-ssl.conf` and here are the contents:

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log
    LogLevel debug
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH
        SSLProtocol all
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem #note I also tried this with a .crt file because I have both
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #    into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #    directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #    works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        #       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        #       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

As of right now `/var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log` is empty .. I did make it to see if that was the problem and still nothing wrote to it. I read somewhere earlier to try `http://example.org:443` and I did that and got a 404: Not found page, but it did load instead of getting the `This site can't provide a secure connection` message. I also uncommented the `extension=mod_ssl.dll` (or similar) line in php.ini to no avail. Not really sure what steps to take next. I tried generating new key/cert combo to see if that was the issue but didn't fix anything. Also ran openssl commands to check if they matched and didn't get any errors.

One other thing I tried is this: `sudo openssl s_client -connect localhost:443`

And result: `139878660703896:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:`

Comment: As per your configuration, the error log is in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and access log is in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. Even though you have `ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log` at the top, it is being overwritten by `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` in your virtual host config (line 16 in your code block) .

Comment: @Dan that makes sense. Unfortunately nothing is being written there either though. Is this error not considered a fatal error?